# Veins : TraCIMobility::getSignals() method information

Tags: veins, sumo

Good afternoon.

I'm using Veins v4.4 and Sumo 0.25 with Omnet++ v4.6.

I was trying to get information about brakes and blinkers: I've found the **VehicleSignal** field in [*TraCISCenarioManager.h*](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/master/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIScenarioManager.h) and the **getSignals()** method in [TraCIMobility.h](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/master/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIMobility.h)  ,  but as soon as I call this function in my code, it runs in exception since I suppose the variable is never updated. Shouldn't it be updated runtime from Sumo?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You found some functionality that was never fully implemented in Veins 4.4. As a quick hack, you can make this work by changing [`line 891 of TraCIScenarioManager.cc`](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.4/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIScenarioManager.cc#L891) to also update each vehicle's *signal* field, e.g., as follows:

```
mm->nextPosition(p, edge, speed, angle, VehicleSignal(signals));
```